# Coloring slices of a pie bar as gradient in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Imagine I have a pie bar in ggplot2,

```
data <- data.frame(cluster = paste("Cluster", 1:3), size = c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33))
data = rbind(data, data)

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(1), fill = cluster, weight=size)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar(theta="y")+ theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_discrete("",breaks=NULL) + scale_y_continuous("",breaks=NULL) +
  theme(panel.border=element_blank(), 
        strip.text=element_blank(), 
        strip.background=element_blank(), 
        legend.position="none", 
        panel.grid=element_blank())
```

There is another vector of strength that I is represented by a vector (0.2, -1, 1). I like to color each slices as a gradient from blue to red. say, blue, for -1, and and red for 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest a clearer data frame which contains all the data at once, created as follows:

```
> data <- data.frame(cluster = paste("Cluster", 1:3), size = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5), strength = c(0.2, -1, 1))
> data
    cluster size strength
1 Cluster 1  0.2      0.2
2 Cluster 2  0.3     -1.0
3 Cluster 3  0.5      1.0
```

And then the following minimal code produces a pie chart with the fill colour diverging on a scale around midpoint zero depending on the cluster's strength value:

```
> ggplot(data, aes( x = factor(1), group = cluster, fill = strength, weight = size)) + geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar( theta = "y") + scale_fill_gradient2()
```

For reference, have a look at the scale_fill_gradient2 doc page examples in the geom_bar doc page:
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient2.html
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html